# How do I create a jquery function so that a clicked button will scroll to the next date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a trigger button with a class of 'next'and I have coded a jquery function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".next").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('got here');
        var currentDate = new Date();
        console.log(currentDate);
        var dateElements = $(".date");

        var nextDateElement = null;
        dateElements.each(function () {
            var date = new Date($(this).text());
            if (date > currentDate) {
                nextDateElement = $(this);
                return false; // Exit the loop
            }
        });

        if (nextDateElement) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: nextDateElement.offset().top
            }, 'slow');
        }
    });
});
```

but I can't get it to work - or even display the console log. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: I would start with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to add some additional padding? Offset defines the top of the element. Try this:

```
scrollTop: nextDateElement.offset().top + 100
```

Other things to try:

1. Confirm your logic is correct. console log all the dates to make sure they're what you expect.
2. Try it without animate

```
$('html').scrollTop( nextDateElement.offset() );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It was the offset and I have now fixed it